# Referencing variables defined in NiFi custom properties

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I am trying to automate configuration deployment in my NiFi cluster using NiFi REST API. I have defined variables as custom properties file:
    `nifi.variable.registry.properties=./conf/dbconfig.properties`

**Contents of** `dbconfig.properties`

```
dbuser=username
dbpass=password
```

I am trying to reference these variables in configuration JSON file as:

```
    {
      "name": "ConnectDB",
      "config": {
      "properties": {
      "Exchange Name": "",
      "Port": "8329",
      "User Name": "${dbuser}",
      "Password": "${dbpass}"
    },
```

However, these registry variables are not picked up during the deployment.
[Processor config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWG4M.png)

Comment: but registry variables substituted on processor run not on creation.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you showed is correct...

If you were doing this through the UI, you would enter ${dbuser} and ${dbpass} as the values in the processors. The processor then evaluates these at runtime to determine the real value.

POSTing via the REST API should be the same thing.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for confirming the behavior. However, it seems like processor is not taking values defined in `dbconfig.properties`, as it shows error connecting to database. Do I need to tweak any processor specific configuration to make this work? like enabling NiFi expression language or something?

Comment: The properties have to support expression language, you can check the docs of each processor to see which ones do, and you also need to restart NiFi if you have made changes to any of the files referenced in nifi.variable.registry.properties

Comment: I had to rebuild my custom processor to enable expression language. Thanks for your guidance, it helped me a lot!